# In GMT after adding scale bar , psxy plots are disappears

Tags: gmt

Here My script is

```
!/bin/bash

LATLON=30/130/-40/20

PROJ=M6i

STASYM=t0.1

STACOLOR=255/0/0

FNAME=map.ps

EPISYM=c0.1

EPICOLOR=255/255/0

gmt grdimage ../../ETOPO1.grd -R${LATLON} -J${PROJ} -C../../sediment.cpt -P -B30 -V -K -Y10 > ${FNAME}  << EOF

EOF

gmt psscale -C../../sediment.cpt -D7.7/-1.0/15/0.4h -P -O -B2000:"Bathymetry & Topography relief":/:meter: -I -V   >> ${FNAME}  << EOF

EOF

#MAP GREAT CIRCLE RAY PATHS USING PROJECT
gmt psxy ./RAYPATH -P -J${PROJ} -R${LATLON} -W0.1 -O -: -V -K >> ${FNAME} << EOF

EOF

#PLOT EPICENTER LOCATIONS

gmt psxy ./EPICENTRE -P -J${PROJ} -R${LATLON} -O -: -S${EPISYM} -W0.2 -G${EPICOLOR} -V -K >> ${FNAME} << EOF

EOF

#PLOT STATION LOCATIONS

gmt psxy ./STATION -P -J${PROJ} -R${LATLON} -O -: -S${STASYM} -W0.2 -G${STACOLOR} -V   >> ${FNAME} << EOF

EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your psscale command misses the -K option. It's always a good habit to have the -O and -K (when both are needed off course) paired together, -O -K, to make it easy to spot mistakes like this.

Also, you don't need any of those (they do nothing but visual noise)

.... << EOF

EOF